# meteor : How to make select based on result of previous select

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I have a form with to select lists in it `countryList` an `stateList` .
each of these has also a collection `countrys` and 'states.

Based on the chosen Country i want that the `stateList` show only those states that belong to the chosen Country.

In the states collection there is a field country so i can filter based on that.

I can't handle the code to create the `stateList` ????

After hours of experimenting and trials and errors i become something like this :

```
Template.registerPartnerStep2.events({
'click #countryList': function (event, template) {
    var x = myTrim($("#countryList").val());
    var y = (Countrys.findOne({country: x}));
    var z = y.nr;


},
'focus #stateList': function (event, template) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var x = myTrim($("#countryList").val());
    var y = (Countrys.findOne({country: x}));
    var z = y.nr;
    if (typeof(this.stateSub) !== 'undefined') {
        this.stateSub.stop();
    }
    this.stateSub = Meteor.subscribe('stateList', z);

}
})
```

Can anybody help me further ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Subscribe to countries at `onCreated`.
2. React to event of countries change/click.
3. After the country changes, subscribe to the state/region list
4. Your state/region list should react when the data arrives, a simple template helper that queries your local collection is enough.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT for Session use:**

```
Template.registerPartnerStep2.events({

    'change #countryList': function () {
        var country = myTrim($("#countryList").val());
        Session.set('selectedCountry', country)
    }

});
```

```
Template.registerPartnerStep2.helpers({

    selectedCountryStates: function () {
        var country = Session.get('selectedCountry');
        return States.find({country: country})
    }

});
```

Comment: How can i make that the  helper function is running after changing a country ??

Comment: You need a listener for this, let's say Session. Set the selected country value as the Session variable and get it from the helper function.